# How do I limit particles to move only on certain axis?

Tags: particles, force-fields

I have a turbulence force field that moves some particles around, but I don't want the particles to move on the Y axis but only on the X or XZ axis. Is there any way to achieve it?

I already tried using wind force fields with no strength and some noise, the effect it's not really the same of a turbulence.

Answer (score 1):

I have made **Extra Nodes** for **Animation Nodes** (blender 2.79, blender 2.80) which allows to control particles very easily. Here is solution for your problem:

[image]

So, in this node-tree, using particle data node, first get the locations of all particles **(unborn, alive, dying which is crucial step)** then multiply the locations with vector (1, 0, 1) which makes y-axis locations zero or limit the particles in the XZ-axis but you can limit them in any axes. Now, use these new locations of particles and plug them into the locations input of the particles output node. Here is tutorial link how to install and use Extra Nodes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvzr8lu5Ef0

Comment: Animation Nodes is an add-on and therefore a workaround, not really a solution, I was already using it without Extra Nodes, just by instancing the particle object and placing the instances into their particle's respective locations.
I didn't know about Extra Nodes tho, I'm already rendering so right now it's too late, but thanks!

Comment: OK. However, extra nodes directly control the particles, so you do not need to do object instances.